# Facebook JS SDK and sub-domains

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies, sdk, subdomain

I realise there are some questions about this already but I'm still a little confused!

For someone to login on my website using Facebook they are directed to secure.mydomain.com. Will the cookie be available on www.mydomain.com after the user has logged on or not? If not then how do I make it available across all domains.

I believe there is a bug in this area https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/256155664428653?browse=search_4e843e6d89a232275456793 but I'm not sure if this has been resolved yet???

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The bug you mentioned is already closed.

Even if cookie is set on your sub-domain and will not be available to server side until set on other sub-domain, if you call `FB.init` with `status` equal to `true` fresh login status of user will be fetched by JavaScript SDK and cookie will be set/updated.

Comment: thanks for that - as I have two different header files (one for each sub-domain) do I need to add the JS part in both under the body tag?

Comment: Not under but within... Citing documentation: - _"The best place to put this code is right after the opening <body> tag."_

Comment: I understand where the JS code goes ...but I need it in both header files right (as i have different header files for each sub-domain), in order to read the cookie across both sub domains? I am on the right lines?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to place it on both sub-domains. And ensure that App domain contain your root domain or every sub-domains you'll use

Answer (score 0):

When I went to your bug link it says: `Status: Fix Ready`.  So in my mind, they haven't deployed the bug fix yet.

However, on each page, no matter the subdomain, you should always call FB.getLoginStatus() (after FB.iniit()) and grab the access token from it's response.

Comment: Hi - yeah I was thinking the same. It reads to me as if they haven't actually made the change yet (or at least haven't told us).

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to use the FB.getLoginStatus() as the basic example that Facebook provides doesn't include this. Mine also appears to be working fine without this but I would like to make use of it if it it will improve things.

Comment: Though this may be because I'm using the PHP SDK in conjunction with JS - is this the right thinking as I'm proper confused now! ha ha

Comment: But i think this is for those using JS alone. As I'm using PHP SDK too it's not necessary - correct me if I'm wrong though!

Comment: No, you can use JS in conjunction with PHP SDK.  Even facebook example apps do that.

Comment: What i meant was that using FB.getLoginStatus was not necessary as I'm using the PHP SDK.

Comment: You wanted a workaround until the bug is fixed.  The FB.getLoginStatus is a very valid workaround.